# can one python script run both with python 2.x and python 3.x

Tags: python, python-3.x

i have thousands of servers(linux), some only has python 2.x and some only has python 3.x, i want to write one script check.py can run on all servers just as $./check.py without use $python check.py or $python3 check.py, is there any way to do this?

my question is how the script check.py find the Interpreter no matter the Interpreter is python2.x and python3.x

Comment: sure ... as long as you use language constructs that are common to both ...

Comment: the problem is how to write the first line #/usr/bin/env python[2.x|3.x] to find the Interpreter

Comment: Why is that a problem? Just run `python`; on a system with only 2.x, or with both 2.x and 3.x, that'll be 2.x; on a system with only 3.x, it should be 3.x.

Comment: lol... i make a mistake,you are right,just use #/usr/bin/env python is enough,thx

Comment: @abarnert Please don't generalize: at least on Arch Linux it's the other way round: `python` == Python 3.x, `python2` == Python 2.x.

Comment: @ack: Arch Linux is doing the wrong thing (for 2011-2014) according to [PEP 394](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0394/), and it's a known problem (in fact, the main reason the PEP was written). But, even taking Arch into account, the comment is still valid: Just run `python`; on a system with only 2.x, or with both 2.x and 3.x except for Arch, that'll be 2.x; on a system with only 3.x, or an Arch system with both, it should be 3.x. As long as you've written code that's compatible with both, it works.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Many scripts can run on both 2.x and 3.x. (I've got a bunch I work on on a daily basis, and I've converted various open source libraries from 2.x-only to dual-version.)

A few things make it much easier:

- Require 2.7, or at least 2.6+, for 2.x users. Otherwise, for example, you cannot raise and exceptions with parameters or catch them into variables, and other such severe limitations.
- Require 3.3+, or at least 3.2+, for 3.x users. Most of the gratuitous incompatibilities (like the `u` prefix being taken away) were reversed in 3.2 or 3.3.
- Use the [six](http://packages.python.org/six/) library.
- Use `__future__` statements.
- Always be clear in your head about whether you mean `bytes` (always 8-bit), `unicode` (must encode if you want 8-bit), or `str` (whatever most of the stdlib APIs expect), and `encode` and `decode` as necessary.
- Regularly run `2to3` on your code. (But don't blindly do everything it says. If, e.g., you're using `d.keys()` or `map(f, l)` because you don't care whether you get back a `list` or not, you'll get a warning, because `2to3` doesn't know you don't care.)

Alternatively, instead of trying to write code that runs on both, write code that runs on 2.x, but can be automatically transformed by `2to3` into running 3.x code, and make that part of your installation process (in `setup.py`, `if sys.version_info >= (3, 0):` do the `2to3` step).

From your edit, it sounds like you're mostly concerned with what to put in the #! line. For that:

```
/usr/bin/env python
```

This isn't guaranteed to work—but then `env` isn't guaranteed to work in the first-place… You can count on the fact that:

- On just about any system where the platform/distro supplies only 2.x, `python` is Python 2.
- On just about any system where the platform/distro supplies both, `python` is Python 2.
- On just about any system where the platform/distro supplies only 3.x (which currently is very rare, but will presumably eventually be more common), `python` is Python 3.

However:

- On a system where the platform supplies *neither*, if the admin only installed 3.x, it will likely (as of early 2013) *not* be available as `python`. There's not much you can do about this one.

If the last one is a serious problem, you can work around it by adding a launcher script, written in sh, that tries `python` and then tries `python3` if that fails.

The nice way to do this is to specify the launcher script itself as the shebang interpreter in your Python script. Linux can handle this, but it's configurable, and at least some distros disable it by default—and most other *nix systems can't do it.

If that doesn't work, the next best option is to make the user run the launcher script—that is, tell them to do `./check.sh` instead of `./check.py`, and `check.sh` figures out the right Python interpreter and runs `$python ./check.py` for the user.

If you want to get really tricky, you could even embed the Python script as a heredoc inside the shell script, so you only need to distribute one file. They run `./check.sh`, and it finds the right Python and runs it on the heredoc.

Comment: thx, i just want to do it this way,but it is not my question,i think run with python3 only can use #!/usr/bin/env python3,a mistake

Comment: @xielingyun: Most popular platforms either only install 2.x, or install both. But there are some systems that do come with neither—and, as I said, if the admin only installs 3.x (especially if he installs from python.org instead of using a distro package) it will probably not be available as `python`. Is this a serious problem for you? If so, exactly what platform are you dealing with?

Comment: @xielingyun: I edited the answer with some general help for that case, but as I said, it won't work on all platforms.

Comment: :it is a problem,my platform is linux(rhel 4.x/5.x/6.x, centos 4.x/5.x/6.x),if it can not be available as `python` and the script can not run, the worker know nothing with python,so the script can just run as ./check.py

Comment: thx for your help, use a shell script to wrapper mybe the best idea

Comment: @xielingyun: I've never used RHEL/Centos 6 in anger, but I thought 4.x and 5.x came with python 2.x as `/usr/bin/python` pre-installed by default, and if you tried to explicitly remove the package it would uninstall half the system. Am I remembering wrong?

Comment: @xielingyun: One more question: I seem to remember RHEL being one of the linux distros that disables using shell scripts as shebang interpreters? So definitely test it before you decide this will work for you. Otherwise, see the edited version for two more variations.

Comment: rhel 6.x has python 2.x now,but mybe remove python 2.x after serveral years, i want to solve this problem.now i have other linux distros(not work platform,so do  not need to solve this problem) without python 2.x and encounter this problem.all platform can use shell scripts,but i think if the distro has no `python` just do  `ln python3 python` is much better..

Comment: @xielingyun: Yes, RHEL or other distros will remove Python 2.x in a few years (although most distros/platforms are thinking on the order of 10 years, not 1 or 2). But the plan is that when they do so, `/usr/bin/python` will run 3.x, not that it will disappear. (As for the `ln python3 python`, if you're talking about suggesting that end-users or admins do that so they can run your program, that doesn't sound like a very good idea.) Do you have a real problem today, or are you worried about what happens a decade from today?

Comment: just worried about a decade from today,not a real problem today

Answer (score 1):

Considering that Python 3.x is not entirely backwards compatible with Python 2.x, you would have to ensure that the script was compatible with both versions.  This can be done with some help from the `2to3` tool, but may ultimately mean running two distinct Python scripts.

Answer (score 0):

In the general case, no; many Python 2 scripts will not run on Python 3, and vice versa. They are two different languages.

Having said that, if you are careful, you can write a script which will run correctly under both. Some authors take extra care to make sure their scripts will be compatible across both versions, commonly using additional tools like the `six` library (the name is a pun; you can get to "six" by multiplying "two by three" or "three by two").

However, it is now 2020, and Python 2 is officially dead. Many maintainers who previously strove to maintain Python 2 compatibility while it was still supported will now be relieved and often outright happy to pull the plug on it going forward.